# How to use overloading operator without the include friend?

Tags: c++

for unit testing:

```
 ostream& operator << (ostream&os,const Unit&C)
 {

     os << C.GetUnitName() << C.GetUnitID() << C.GetCredits();
     return os;
 }

 istream& operator >> (istream&input,Unit&C)
 {
     string UnitName,UnitsID;
     int Crediet;
     input >> UnitName >> UnitsID>> Crediet;

    C.setUnitName(UnitName);
    C.setUnitID(UnitsID);
    C.setCredits(Crediet);

    return input;
}
```

text input file: Database ICT222 3

why I get the outfile:"0x6afd64"?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. For example, what is `Unit`? How are the member functions you call declared? We need to know that.

Comment: The error is probably in the non-exposed code.

Comment: Can it be the question title not matching the actual question?

Comment: Strongly consider just making them `friend`s if you would otherwise write public getters & setters to expose the data members. It is **more encapsulated** to have a pair of `friend`s going through your `private`s than having *any code anywhere* able to see and change the values.

Comment: The pattern I use is to have the `operator<<` and `operator>>` streaming free standing glue functions call public member functions `void print(std::ostream&) const` and `void read(std::istream&)`.  For a polymorphic inheritance hierarchy, they are virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to use overloading operator without the include friend?

You can *always* overload without friend provided you *onl*y use *public* members of your class in the operator...

If you *need* internals, bad luck, then you *need* a friend declaration. You might compile it in conditionally, though, for your testing builds only:

```
class C
{
#ifdef SOME_MACRO_IDENTIFYING_UT_BUILD
    friend auto operator<<(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
#endif
};
```

You won't be able to prevent the user having the macro defined, too, though. Variant:

```
class C
{
#ifdef SOME_MACRO_IDENTIFYING_UT_BUILD
    friend
#endif
     auto operator<<(/*...*/); // no implementation in header
};
```

(or just skip the ifdef/endif entirely, would not matter much...)

In the CPP file then (which would already be compiled, so user cannot influence unless having sources; not applicable for templates, though):

```
#ifdef SOME_MACRO_IDENTIFYING_UT_BUILD
auto operator<<(/* ... */)
{
    // implementation showing your internals
}
#else
auto operator<<(/* ... */)
{
    // some implementation you consider safe for general use...
    //
    // if you don't want the user to use it at all, you
    // even might throw an exception - I don't consider
    // it the best idea, but at least...
}
#endif
```

All you yet need to do is having your specific test build run with the macro defined, GCC/clang: -D option, MSVC /D.